# How to re-order a List<String>

Tags: java, list, locale

I have created the following method:

```
public List<String> listAll() {
    List worldCountriesByLocal = new ArrayList();

    for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
        final String isoCountry = locale.getDisplayCountry();
        if (isoCountry.length() > 0) {
            worldCountriesByLocal.add(isoCountry);
            Collections.sort(worldCountriesByLocal);
        }
    }
    return worldCountriesByLocal;
}
```

Its pretty simple and it returns a list of world countries in the users locale. I then sort it to get it alphabetic. This all works perfectly (except I seem to occasionally get duplicates of countries!).

Anyway, what I need is to place the US, and UK at the top of the list regardless. The problem I have is that I can't isolate the index or the string that will be returned for the US and UK because that is specific to the locale!

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getCountry()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a `TreeSet` to eliminate duplicates and your own `Comparator` to bring US and GB up to the start.

You are getting duplicates (which this will eliminate) because there are often more than one locale per country. There is a US(Spanish) as well as a US(English) and there are three Switzerlands (French, German and Italian) for example.

```
public class AllLocales {
  // Which Locales get priority.
  private static final Locale[] priorityLocales = {
    Locale.US,
    Locale.UK
  };

  private static class MyLocale implements Comparable<MyLocale> {
    // My Locale.
    private final Locale me;

    public MyLocale(Locale me) {
      this.me = me;
    }

    // Convenience
    public String getCountry() {
      return me.getCountry();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyLocale it) {
      // No duplicates in the country field.
      if (getCountry().equals(it.getCountry())) {
        return 0;
      }
      // Check for priority ones.
      for (int i = 0; i < priorityLocales.length; i++) {
        Locale priority = priorityLocales[i];
        // I am a priority one.
        if (getCountry().equals(priority.getCountry())) {
          // I come first.
          return -1;
        }
        // It is a priority one.
        if (it.getCountry().equals(priority.getCountry())) {
          // It comes first.
          return 1;
        }
      }
      // Default to straight comparison.
      return getCountry().compareTo(it.getCountry());
    }
  }

  public static List<String> listAll() {
    Set<MyLocale> byLocale = new TreeSet();
    // Gather them all up.
    for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
      final String isoCountry = locale.getDisplayCountry();
      if (isoCountry.length() > 0) {
        //System.out.println(locale.getCountry() + ":" + isoCountry + ":" + locale.getDisplayName());
        byLocale.add(new MyLocale(locale));
      }
    }
    // Roll them out of the set.
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MyLocale l : byLocale) {
      list.add(l.getCountry());
    }
    return list;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // Some demo usages.
    List<String> locales = listAll();
    System.out.println(locales);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> Anyway, what I need is to place the US, and UK at the top of the list regardless. The problem I have is that I can't isolate the index or the string that will be returned for the US and UK because that is specific to the locale!

It sounds like you should implement your own [`Comparator<Locale>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to compare two locales with the following steps:

- If the locales are the same, return 0
- If one locale is the US, make that "win"
- If one locale is the UK, make that "win"
- Otherwise, use `o1.getDisplayCountry().compareTo(o2.getDisplayCountry())` (i.e. delegate to existing behaviour)

(This will put the US before the UK.)

Then call [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with an instance of your custom comparator.

Do all of this *before* extracting the country names - then extract them from the sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

yes, when you do sort, just provide your own comparator

Collections.sort(worldCountriesByLocal, new Comparator() {

```
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1.equals(TOP_VALUE))
            return -1;
        if (o2.equals(TOP_VALUE))
            return 1;
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
})
```

where top value will be value what you want to always on top

Answer (score 1):

I would write my own POJO with a sort token consisting of an integer assigning priority (e.g. 0 for US, 1 for UK, 2 for everyone else), then some delimiter and then the country name.  Then I would put the array in a HashMap keyed by that sort ID and the POJO as the val.  Then I would sort the keys out of the map and iterate through the sorting and retrieve the plain country name for each sorted key.

E.g.

```
2.Sweden
2.France
2.Tanzania
0.US
1.UK
```

sorts

```
0.US
1.UK
2.France
2.Sweden
2.Tanzania
```

EDIT:  a POJO is needed only if you have more fields other than the country name. If it is just the country name, I would set the sort ID as the hash key and the country name as the val and skip the POJO part.