# Equals and Comparable with Sets

Tags: java, equals, comparable, compareto, treeset

I posted some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12748832/823393) which correctly solved a problem the poster had. OP wanted to remove duplicates and bring certain special items to the top of a list. I used a `TreeSet` with a special `Comparable` class which wrapped the `Locale` they were working with to achieve what they wanted.

I then got to thinking ... as you do ... that I was eliminating duplicates by returning `0` from the `compareTo` method, not by returning `true` from an `equals` implementation as one would need to do to correctly indicate a duplicate in a `Set` (from the [definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of a `Set`).

I have no objection to using this technique but am I using what might be considered an *undocumented feature*? Am I safe to assume that doing this kind of thing going forward will continue to work?

Comment: As Mr Nurkiewicz points out, this is specified behaviour, so it's safe. I do agree that it's surprising, though!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems like this is pretty well documented in [JavaDoc of `TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (bold mine):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) **must be consistent with equals** if it is to correctly implement the `Set` interface. (See `Comparable` or `Comparator` for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the `Set` interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation, but a **`TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or compare) method**, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. **The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the `Set` interface**.

Here is an example of the [only (?) JDK class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) that implements `Comparable` but is not consistent with `equals()`:

```
Set<BigDecimal> decimals = new HashSet<BigDecimal>();
decimals.add(new BigDecimal("42"));
decimals.add(new BigDecimal("42.0"));
decimals.add(new BigDecimal("42.00"));
System.out.println(decimals);
```

`decimals` at the end have three values because `42`, `42.0` and `42.00` are not equal as far as `equals()` is concerned. But if you replace `HashSet` with `TreeSet`, the resulting set contains only 1 item (`42` - that happened to be the first one added) as all of them are considered equal when compared using [`BigDecimal.compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)).

This shows that `TreeSet` is in a way "*broken*" when using types not consistent with `equals()`. It still works properly and all operations are well-defined - it just doesn't obey the contract of `Set` class - if two classes are not `equal()`, they are not considered duplicates.

## See also

- [What does comparison being consistent with equals mean ? What can possibly happen if my class doesn't follow this principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123960)

Comment: Interesting that there is no such comment in the `ConcurrentSkipListSet` docs.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon It is actually also specified in the [javadoc of SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) (and both TreeSet and ConcurrentSkipListSet implement that interface).