# what is the difference between equals and contains methods

Tags: java, collections, treeset

I was working with the `TreeSet` collection with the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{

    private int ID;

    public Employee(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee obj) {
        return this.ID-obj.ID;
    }

    private static void intoTreeSet() {
        Employee e1=new Employee(4);
        Employee e2=new Employee(2);
        Employee e3=new Employee(1);
        Employee e4=new Employee(5);
        Employee e5=new Employee(3);

        Employee eTemp=new Employee(3);

        Set<Employee> set=new TreeSet();
        set.add(e1);set.add(e2);set.add(e3);set.add(e4);set.add(e5);

        System.out.println("output says: ");
        for(Employee e:set){
            System.out.print(e.ID+" ~ ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        if(set.contains(eTemp)){
            System.out.println("C O N T A I N S !!!");
        }

        if(e5.equals(eTemp)){
            System.out.println("E Q U A L S !!!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        intoTreeSet();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
output says: 
1 ~ 2 ~ 3 ~ 4 ~ 5 ~ 
C O N T A I N S !!!
```

I am confused to see the output. I want to know, if it does NOT pass `equals` case, then how come it pass `contains` case.

I know that two objects can only be equal if their class overrides `equals` method and they are equal according to some property. I intentionally did not override `equals` method to see how `contains` work. If it were a non-tree based collection lets say an `ArrayList` it would NOT have passed `contains` test. Why is it so ? can any one explain this behaviour and clear my confusion.

Comment: "a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal."

Comment: A similar question from a couple of years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761532/equals-and-comparable-with-sets

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476600/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important point to remember here is, a `TreeSet` is a [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) which performs element comparisons using `compareTo (or compare)` method.

The Employee class is *comparable*. From the definition from the docs of the comparable interface,

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class
>   that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's
>   natural ordering, and the class's **compareTo method is referred to as
>   its natural comparison method.**

So if your `compareTo` method returns `0`, for two instances of the same class, they are considered to be naturally equal by the `TreeSet`.

The document also says,

> It is **strongly recommended (though not required)** that natural orderings **be consistent with 
>   equals.** This is so because sorted sets (and sorted maps) without explicit
>   comparators **behave "strangely"** when they are used with elements (or
>   keys) whose natural ordering is inconsistent with equals.

Though it is not defined how "strangely" it can behave.

In our case `e5.equals(eTemp)` is `false`, since the `equals` method is not overridden.
And `e5.compareTo(eTemp)` is `true`, so from the set's perspective `e5` and `eTemp` are equal.

To demonstrate this you can perform the below operations:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(3);
Employee e2 = new Employee(3);
set.add(e1); // gets added to the set
```

The below operation will return `false` because the set considers an equivalent of `e2` already to be present in the set, though `e1.equals(e2)` is `false`, and the size of the set remains same.

```
System.out.println(set.add(e2));  // false
```

So to to be consistent, you could override the `equals` method, though it is not necessary.

Comment: Wow. It was a great explanation. No confusion, no doubt, just more knowledge. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

[The javadoc for `java.util.TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) says:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) **must be consistent with equals** if it is to correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set interface.

In other words, the implementations of `compareTo` and `equals` must be consistent with each other. If they're not, the behaviour of `TreeSet` will be erratic. It *may* work, it may not. To understand when it does and when it doesn't you need to look closely at the `TreeSet` implementation, but since the javadoc is very explicit on the conditions under which `TreeSet` works, it's really not a good idea to try and subvert it.

Comment: An all-time classic. I have seen at least 50 questions tagged 'treeset' which basically ask the same question and get the same (correct) answer. I wonder why so many people do not search here before asking. ;-)